# How to set transparency of translucent navigation bar in iOS7?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uinavigationbar, navigationbar, translucency

I searched and tried as below, but doesn't work. In fact, event set `translucent = YES` can't make the navigation bar translucent.Does anyone know?

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.alpha = 0.7f;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
```

Comment: did you try to set the transparency via the attributes inspector? here is a link to a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21181499/navigation-bar-becomes-transparent-when-set-to-translucent/21182784#21182784)

Comment: I write the views and layout programmingly without `StoryBoard` or `nib` files.

Comment: This can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20319439/how-to-make-navigation-bar-transparent-in-ios-7
But the blur effect will not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's late, but if anyone need the answer here it is.
If you want transparency in all navigationBar than write following lines in your AppDelegate's 
`-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` 
method:

**## Objective C ##**

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setShadowImage:[UIImage new]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTranslucent:YES];
```

**## Swift ##**

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
UINavigationBar.appearance().translucent = true
```

For transparency in particular view, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18969325/1459192).

Answer (score -2):

It should work if you click on the segue between the 2 views in storyboard, then in the attribute "Inspector -> in presentation" select "over Full Screen"

Comment: As it currently stands, it is hard to tell what you mean. Could you expand your answer a bit? Does the OP need to change something in the code or adjust something in the configuration of his/her project?

Comment: click on the segue between the 2 views in storyboard, then in the attribute Inspector - > in presentation select "over Full Screen"