# statusBar becomes transparent when searchBar is active

Tags: iphone, swift

I have a `UISearchController` in my view controller, when the `searchBar` is active the status bar becomes transparent. I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35563770/hidden-statusbar-reappears-when-searchbar-gets-activated) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21181499/navigation-bar-becomes-transparent-when-set-to-translucent) but none of them worked.

[image]

This is the view hierarchy of the view controller:

[image]

How can I make the status bar translucent?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32235444/2108547

Comment: @DanielStorm It was tricky but this http://stackoverflow.com/a/34229176/689779 worked. if you post it an answer, i'll mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this in `viewDidLoad` solved the problem:

```
var frame = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame
        frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: frame.height*3.3)
//3.3 is a practical number
        let statusBarView = UIView(frame: frame)
        statusBarView.backgroundColor = sharedApplication.mainThemeColor
        searchController.view.addSubview(statusBarView)
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me without multiplying by `3.3` and I also used  `statusBarView.backgroundColor = searchController.view.backgroundColor` to make sure they have the same color.